# Sum all numbers 0 to x that are divisible by y using while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to write a script using a while loop (not using the for function whatsoever) to sum all numbers between 0 and x that are divisible by div1.
This is what I have.

```
def sum_upto_divisible(x,div1):
    i=0
    while i<x:
        i+=1
        if i%div1==0:
            i+=i
    return(i)
```

If x = 25 and div1=5, the answer should be 50.  My current loop gives me an answer of 30.  I understand that the loop is adding until 5, then doubling it. Then it returns to adding 1 to i (now 10) until it hits 15.  Then it doubles 15 and the loop ceases.  I need to add 5, 10, 15, and 20.  How can I fix the loop I have now?

Comment: You're using `i` both as the loop incriminator and as the accumulator (sum) which messes things up. Use a different variable to accumulate the sum.

Comment: Of course, one might ask why you are adding 1 each time through. Is there a number smaller than `div1` that is divisible by `div1`?

Comment: Thank you very much! I added another variable and I got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_upto_divisible(x,div1):
    if div1 < 0 :
        div1 = -div1
    i=0
    s=0
    while i < x:
        s += i
        i += div1
    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_upto_divisible(x, div1):
    return sum([num for num in x if num % div1 == 0])
```